# How to make animations in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, animation, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library for rendering of charts. While using i came across this piece of code :

```
public void animateY(int durationmillis, Easing.EasingOption option);
```

What is animation easing? What is the use of Easing.EasingOption?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting it simple, animation-easing allows you to **modify the way something animates**.

[This documentation entry](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/animations/) explains animations in MPAndroidChart.

Comment: Does animation works if we implement custom Chart rendering class and method?